# ASP.net -Trying to associate one primary key to multiple foreign keys

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a list of Ingredients that exist that contain a primary key: ingredientID and a foreign key: recipeID. I have been trying to map a single ingredient to many Recipes, which each contain a recipeID and an ingredientID.

Previously, I assigned the Ingreients recipeID to the same as the target Recipes recipeID. this restrained the Ingredient to being associated with a single Recipe however.

By associating the Recipes ingredientID with an ingredient, it seems that Recipe can then only have one Ingredient associated with it, but that Ingredient can be associated with other recipes.

I have tried to create a recipeIngredient that contains a recipeID and an ingredientID to associate Recipes and Ingredients, but I had no success.

Here is a description of the current models.

Recipe Model:

```
    [Key]
    public int recipeID { get; set; }
    public int ingredientID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public virtual NutritionalValue NutritionalDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecipeStep> RecipieSteps { get; set; }
```

Ingredient Model:

```
    [Key]
    public int ingredientID { get; set; }
    //public int recipeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descritpion { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
```

The final concept from this that I am trying to achieve is that the user selects an ingredient within the Recipes edit view, selects the ingredient that was already previously added and clicks save to associate it with that particular Recipe, but can also go on to associate it with further Recipes simultaneously.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want each recipe to have multiple ingredients, but you want there to be an ingredients table that doesn't duplicate entries. This is actually more like a many to many relationship. If that's the case, your database schema needs to change to something like this:

```
Ingredient(id (pk), name, etc...)
Recipe(id (pk), name, etc...)
RecipeIngredients(recipeId (fk to Recipe.id), ingredientId (fk to ingredient.id))
```

This way recipes can have multiple ingredients via the RecipeIngredients table, and there is still a table (Ingredient) that represents 1 ingredient per tuple and 1 recipe per tuple (Recipe).

LMK if that helps :)